# How to re-process an existing Autodesk file with updated version?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

We have a scenario where Box(box.com) has multiple versions for same file and we need to update and process the current version of file in our application.

Please let me know the process to upload new file version in same bucket and process it.

Currently, we are unable to render the updated Autodesk file view. It is still showing the old file view.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply upload a new version of the file using the same bucketKey/objectKey pair, first make sure that you are using `x-ads-force` set to `true` in the header of your [/POST job](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/) request.

The viewer is caching the data when loading a model, so once the translation is done, you also need to make sure you are clearing your cache or testing in incognito session.

See that article for more details: [I Make Changes and Nothing Happens](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/i-make-changes-and-nothing-happens)

Hope that helps.